# TypeError: chunk.isInitial is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

I am trying to run build my program with

```
    "build": "NODE_ENV='production' webpack -p",
```

I get an error

```
node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/index.js:267
            var shouldExtract = !!(options.allChunks || 
  chunk.isInitial());
TypeError: chunk.isInitial is not a function
```

I have installed webpack 2.6.1 and extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.1.0 
What I should to do?

Comment: webpack `3.10.10` does not exists, what's your real version?

Comment: It was a mistake, 2.6.1

Answer (score 0):

you're probably using an old version of Webpack, simply change the version in package.json to 3.1.0.